# Getting Warning on Play Store for using WRITE_CALL_LOG permission in android app

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm working on a project based on cloud backup which saves and restore user's call log. It was working fine for the previous version but now getting following warning. I added a description before taking permission from the user but still getting the warning.

> Your app is requesting the following permission which is used by less
>   than 1% of functionally similar apps: WRITE_CALL_LOG
>
> Users prefer apps that request fewer permissions and requesting
>   unnecessary permissions can affect your app's visibility on the Play
>   Store. If these permissions aren't necessary, you may be able to use
>   alternative methods in your app and request fewer permissions. If they
>   are, we recommend providing an explanation to users of why you need
>   the permissions. Learn more
>
> Note: This guidance is based on a comparison with functionally similar
>   apps, which change over time as new apps get published and existing
>   apps change behavior. Therefore the warning may change even if you
>   don't change your permission usage.

Answer (score 0):

Its a warning.  If you need that permission (and it seems your app does), then you're fine.  If you didn't really need it, you should remove it.  Google isn't going to scan your description to see if you explain it, that level of AI isn't really possible yet.  So you'll continue to get the warning.